# Test Method That Accepts Date Parameter Doesn't work

Tags: unit-test, class, date

I'm posting the challenge question to the Trailhead Beginner 'Apex Unit Tests' module.

Install a simple Apex class, write unit tests that achieve 100% code coverage for the class, and run your Apex tests.

### The original Apex class is:

```
public class VerifyDate {

    //method to handle potential checks against two dates
    public static Date CheckDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
        //if date2 is within the next 30 days of date1, use date2.  Otherwise use the end of the month
        if(DateWithin30Days(date1,date2)) {
            return date2;
        } else {
            return SetEndOfMonthDate(date1);
        }
    }

    //method to check if date2 is within the next 30 days of date1
    private static Boolean DateWithin30Days(Date date1, Date date2) {
        //check for date2 being in the past
            if( date2 < date1) { return false; }

            //check that date2 is within (>=) 30 days of date1
            Date date30Days = date1.addDays(30); //create a date 30 days away from date1
        if( date2 >= date30Days ) { return false; }
        else { return true; }
    }

    //method to return the end of the month of a given date
    private static Date SetEndOfMonthDate(Date date1) {
        Integer totalDays = Date.daysInMonth(date1.year(), date1.month());
        Date lastDay = Date.newInstance(date1.year(), date1.month(), totalDays);
        return lastDay;
    }
```

---

### My test class is:

```
@isTest
private class TestVerifyDate {

    @isTest static void DateWithin30Days(){

         Date date3 = VerifyDate.CheckDates(01/01/2015, 01/02/2015); 

         System.assert(01/02/2015, date3); 
    }
}
```

---

The problem I'm seeing is that 01/01/2015 and 01/02/2015 are not accepted as Dates. I've also tried 2015-01-01 and 2015-01-02 but with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to format the test class are much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate a date by using the `Date` class:

`Date.newInstance(2015, 2, 1);`

So when you assert you can do:

```
 System.assert(Date.newInstance(2015, 2, 1), date3);
```